# Regex / Pattern, Matcher - Exclude a specific Match

Tags: apex, regular-expressions

Related to the matching of IBAN Numbers: Given this regex pattern `((?:DE)[0-9]{20})` is there a way to exclude specifically the IBAN Number e.g. `DE02120300000000202051` directly in the regex pattern or do I have to exclude it e.g. in the while loop for example. Which route would you suggest. Thank you!

```
private static final String IBAN_PATTERN = '((?:DE)[0-9]{20})';

Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile(IBAN_PATTERN);
Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(String);
while (MyMatcher.find()) {
     System.debug('check ' + MyMatcher.group(1));
}
```

Comment: `if (stringToBeMatched == 'DE02120300000000202051')`, skip regex.  Or use one of the `contains` methods in String

Comment: Using a negative lookahead in the regex ?  (?!DE02120300000000202051)(?:DE)[0-9]{20}

Comment: @OlivierRoc thank you for idea - I like it a lot and it's the best solution for my use case I guess. Cheers!!

Comment: @OlivierRoc You should post that as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to specifically exclude this IBAN as an exception, you may use a negative lookahead in the regex, using the (?!...) syntax.

In your example:

```
String iban = 'DE91100000000123456789,DE02120300000000202051,DE89370400440532013000';

private static final String IBAN_PATTERN = '((?!DE02120300000000202051)(?:DE)[0-9]{20})';
Pattern MyPattern = Pattern.compile(IBAN_PATTERN);
Matcher MyMatcher = MyPattern.matcher(iban);
while (MyMatcher.find()) {
  System.debug('check ' + MyMatcher.group(1));
}
```

Output:

```
USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|check DE91100000000123456789
USER_DEBUG|[8]|DEBUG|check DE89370400440532013000
```

PS: Following @adrian-larson's advice, I'm posting this previous comment as an answer. Thank you Adrian!